# Mongoose - Query inside of multiple nested arrays and return all matches

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user I want to find

```
export const profileSchema = new Schema({
  _user: { type: String, required: true },
  userName: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

I have a schema that could contain that user in many nested places (user or users property)

```
export const publicTaskSchema = new Schema({
  task: { required: true, type: String },
  user: { type: profileSchema, required: true },
  likes: {
    likes: { required: false, type: Number, default: 0 },
    users: { required: false, type: [profileSchema], default: [] },
  },
  comments: [{ 
    user: { required: true, type: profileSchema },
    comment: { required: true, type: String },
    likes: {
      likes: { required: false, type: Number, default: 0 },
      users: { required: false, type: [profileSchema], default: [] },
     },
   }]
});
```

I want to find and return every instance where the queried user is in any of those nested user/users properties. So far I just can't figure out how to do this.

I first want to figure out how to return every match but my end goal is to modify the user documents inside each one that is found. This is along the lines of what I want to do

```
  const found = await PublicTaskList.find<PublicTaskListType>({
          // find all documents that match these:
          "tasks.$[].user._user": req.user._user,
          "tasks.$[].likes.users.$[]._user": req.user._user,
          "tasks.$[].comments$[].user._user": req.user._user,
        }).exec();
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: You shouldn't have `$[]` in your query. You should able to query with dot notation path.